# Compiling Asterisk 1.6.2 on MacOSX Server

Tags: compiler-construction, macos, asterisk

I get this error while trying to compile Asterisk 1.6.2 on Snow Leopard Server :

```
ld: symbol dyld_stub_binding_helper not defined 
         (usually in crt1.o/dylib1.o/bundle1.o)
```

Googling this I’ve found nothing enlightening so far.

This is what I am trying:

```
./configure  --without-h323 --without-zaptel --host=x86_64-darwin
make menuselect
make
```

Comment: I thought as of Asterisk 1.6 it wasn't Zaptel but DAHDI... I've never had to use the --host argument.

Answer (score 0):

Jeremy,
Magically, there was a patch committed today to Asterisk trunk that "make[s] Mac OS X 10.6 happy". http://svnview.digium.com/svn/asterisk?view=revision&revision=251262

This has also been merged to 1.6.2: http://svnview.digium.com/svn/asterisk?view=revision&revision=251268

Try checking out the latest rev of 1.6.2 in svn and see if this resolves your issue.

Comment: Amazing coincidence, many thanks for the heads up.
Unfortunately I cannot even finish the compile now, it hangs on chan_sip.c which is something I have seen reported before, hmmmm

Comment: If I use make menuselect to remove the SIP Channel, Asterisk now compiles and links. But of course it’s not much good without SIP ;-)

Comment: Have you searched through or reported this to https://issues.asterisk.org/main_page.php ?

Comment: I could find nothing quite like it, so posted it as a new issue : https://issues.asterisk.org/view.php?id=16997

Comment: already patched, tested, and committed, go asterisk dev team!

Comment: It has been fixed!
http://svnview.digium.com/svn/asterisk?revision=251496&view=revision
Thanks for your help ocdcoder.